# Skips first line of while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

```
ask=1;
while(ask==1)
{
    System.out.println("What is your phrase?");
    phrase=sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is your additive key?");
    key=sc.nextInt();
    String code=addit(phrase, key);
    System.out.println(code);
    System.out.println("Enter 1 to go again");
    ask=sc.nextInt();
}
```

Skips straight to asking what my additive key is after the first time through the loop anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, based on what @PakkuDon is saying, this should fix the problem:

```
ask = 1;
while(ask == 1)
{
    System.out.println("What is your phrase?");
    phrase = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is your additive key?");
    key = sc.nextInt();
    String code = addit(phrase, key);
    System.out.println(code);
    System.out.println("Enter 1 to go again");
    ask = sc.nextInt();
    String tmp = sc.nextLine();
}
```